# Powershell file rename syntax

Tags: powershell, rename

I'm trying to rename all the files in a given directory so that they have the sequential format 001a.jpg, 001b.jpg, 002a.jpg etc.

I have tried:

```
$c=1
get-childitem * | foreach {
if($c/2=[int]($c/2)){
rename-item -NewName {($c-1) + 'b.jpg'} else rename-item - NewName {$c + 'a.jpg'}}$c++} - whatif
```

But I am getting "the assignment operator is not valid".

The = in the third line is obviously not supposed to be an assignment operator. I just want to check whether the counter is on an even number. I found -ne for not equal to but PS didn't seem to like the -.

I am not sure about the syntax of the new names but the parser doesn't get that far ATM.

Grateful for any pointers.

Edit: I've just realised the numbers would skip but I can fix that once I understand the problem with what I already have.

Comment: Leave spaces around comparison operators `-eq`, `-ne` etc, otherwise the dash is seen as a minus to the equasion `$c/2`

Comment: P.S. to test if a number is odd, it might be quicker to do `if ($c % 2)` or `if ($c -band 1)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think the comparison operator is OK now but there seems to a problem with the foreach. I am getting "ForEach-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'RemainingScripts'. Cannot convert the "-" value of type "System.String" to type
"System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock"."

Comment: Because of your edit "_I can fix that once I understand the problem with what I already have_" I only addressed the comparison problem you had. Petty you didn't ask to review/repair all of your code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things you need to know (some are just recommendations):

1. Every if-else branch requires curly brackets
2. If you do not input the items to `Rename-Item` via the pipeline, you have to specify the path
3. If you specify the path for `Rename-Item`, you cannot use a script block for `-NewName`
4. You cannot use `+` if the left operand is `int` and the right is `string`, because it would be interpreted as addition and requires two numbers.
5. You cannot use the `-WhatIf` switch on the whole construct, but only individual commands
6. It will suffice to use the command only once, and use the if-else only to set the new name
7. You can simplify your condition using the modulus operator `%` (as explained in other answers and comments)
8. You can use the `-Begin` parameter for initialization
9. The `*` for `Get-ChildItem` is not necessary

Here is the updated code:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem | foreach -Begin { $c = 1 } -Process {
    if ($c % 2) {
        $newName = "${c}a.jpg"
    }
    else {
        $newName = "$($c-1)b.jpg"
    }
    Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName $newName -WhatIf
    $c++
}
```

Here is an even shorter version, that pipes directly into `Rename-Item`

```
$c = 0
Get-ChildItem |
  Rename-Item -NewName {if (++$script:c % 2) {"${c}a.jpg"} else {"$($c-1)b.jpg"}} -WhatIf
```

Answer (score 3):

As commented, if you do not leave spaces around the `-eq` or `-ne` operators, PowerShell will interpret the dash as belonging to the math, so

```
if($c/2-ne[int]($c/2))
```

Will fail.

Also, to test if a number is odd, it is probably quicker to do `if ($c % 2)` or `if ($c -band 1)`.

Use `-not` to test for even numbers.